# javascriptの配列のundefinedをゼロで埋めたい

Tags: javascript

タイトル通りなのですが、配列のundefinedをゼロで埋めるため以下のコードを実行したのですが思い通りの動きをしてくれません。

```
[0,1,2,3,,,,,,9].map(function(v){return v||0;}) // -> [0,1,2,3,,,,,,9]
```

scores.forEach()で何回ループするか確認してみたところ、5回しかループしませんでした。
kockoutjsのdata-bind内部に書くコードなので、できるだけ１行で済ませたいと思っています。

どうすればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Int32Array にしてから Array に戻すとかはどうでしょうか

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(new Int32Array([0,1,2,3,,,,,,9]))
// [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]
```

Comment: TypeError: Function is not a function (evaluating 'Int32Array([0,1,2,3,,,,,,9])')というエラーが表示されてしまいました。

Comment: Chrome で "TypeError: Constructor Int32Array requires 'new'" となっていたので Int32Array の前に new を付けるように変更してみました。これでどうでしょうか？

Comment: 無事動きました！有難うございましたm(_ _)m

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.apply(null, sparseArray)
```

とすれば、[[HasProperty]]=falseによるundefined -> undefinedという値 の変換ができます
ですが、読みにくい・理解されにくいので

```
function makeArray(n) {
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        array[i] = undefined;
    }
    return array;
}
```

といった関数を作るか、_.rangeを利用するのがよいと思います

下のブログにも書いてありますが、地道にfor文を記述したほうが速いようです
要素数が大きい配列を作成する、何度も配列を作成する場合は気をつけたほうがよさそうです
http://blog.scheakur.com/post/96000209437/javascript-0-n-1-array